# jquery live change and default load, default not working

Tags: jquery

i have this so when page loads gets value and if true to show a msg which worked but when i used change the change did not so i then used live change function which worked when you changed but now the default check on load does not? any ideas around this?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
                var target = $('.product-options select').find(":selected").val();
                if(target == "2" || target == "4"){
                        $(".beans-msg").html("would you like beans?").show();
                } else {
                    $(".beans-msg").hide();
                }
                console.log(target);
                $('.product-options select').live('change',function(){
                    var changedVal = $(this).find(":selected").val();
                    if(changedVal == "2" || changedVal == "4"){
                        $(".beans-msg").html("would you like beans?").show();
                    } else {
                        $(".beans-msg").hide();
                    }
                    console.log(changedVal);
                });
            });
```

Comment: live() is deprecated ?

Comment: i know but this software uses v1.5.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's jQuery 1.5.2, on() is not supported, but try something like this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.product-options select').live('change', function() {
        var beans = $.trim( this.value );
        if (beans == "2" || beans == "4") {
            $(this).closest('tr')
                   .find(".beans-msg")
                   .html("would you like beans?").show();
        } else {
            $(this).closest('tr')
                   .find(".beans-msg")
                   .hide();
        }
        console.log(beans);
    }).trigger('change');
});
```

If the change function works, just trigger it on pageload ?

Comment: kind of works however, its for a cart page so will be more than 1 and i just tested with 3 but default and change attaches to all 3 rather than each one

Comment: You'll need to explain that better. There are three selects, all dynamic and all with that class, and change happens to all of them when one is changed, or what exactly ?

Comment: yea each item listed has same class wrapper around them, the original code worked so it done it for each but yours seems to set default to all of them and on change changes them all. but yes when one is changed they all changed and sets the default msg to all as well

Comment: Changed it a little bit to a more conventional look, try it now ?

Comment: not loading default if val is true, and its again doing it for all 3, change 1 select and all of them changed :(

Comment: The text changed, i.e. "Would you like beans", or did the actual dropdowns change their value when one is changed ?

Comment: values are as they should be, 1 has val 2 others dont but msg shows on all a nd should show on 1 and change one and they all change

Comment: I'm not sure how that would work any different in your original code, as the html is set on **all** elements that has the `.beans_msg` class. If there are several of those elements, each attached to a select, you'll have to target them somehow, but I can't say how you'd go about that without knowing what the HTML markup would look like ?

Comment: yep that seems to work a treat! thanks for your time and effort mate

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {   
var x = $('.product-options').find(':selected').val();        
        if (x == "2" || x == "4")
            $('.beans-msg').html("would you like beans?").show();
        $('.product-options').live('change',function(){                
            var changedVal = $(this).find(':selected').val();                
                if(changedVal == "2" || changedVal == "4"){
                    $('.beans-msg').html("would you like beans?").show();
                } else {
                    $('.beans-msg').hide();
                }
            });
        });
```

fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UTHsg/)